# CMake - Remove arguments

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I'm having some trouble with Cmake. It seems I'v done something that makes Cmake add arguments when I start my project. Below is my run configuration.

[image: Current settings]

When I debug it I can see that `argv` has the value:

```
"/home/gel/unix/DB1457--LAB2/cmake-build-debug/lab2"
```

(It's the path to the compiled object-file).

If anything, it should be `-p 8080`, right?

Here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(lab2)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SORUCE_FILES "webserver/src/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_HEADERS "webserver/includes/*.h")


set(INCLUDE_DIRS "webserver/includes")
foreach (_headerFile $(SOURCE_HEADERS))
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
        list (APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES INCLUDE_DIRS)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(lab2 ${SORUCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(lab2 Threads::Threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the first string in `argv` is always the path of the executable. Actual parameters start at index 1.

In your example `argv[1]` will contain "-p" and `argv[2]` will have "8080" since they are two separate parameters. If you want them to be passed as one parameter you either need to enclose them in quotes or remove the space between them.